# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." car было null

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio

В работе программы на c# наблюдается ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

car было null.

Ошибка в этой части кода:  car.Row["Статус"] = "[свободна]" - не дает автомобиль в программе сделать свободным, а закрывает приложение ошибкой. Как можно было бы это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var car = aVTOMOBILIBindingSource.Current as DataRowView;
        car.Row["Статус"] = "[свободна]";
        aVTOMOBILIBindingSource.EndEdit();
        aVTOMOBILITableAdapter.Update(carRentDataSet.AVTOMOBILI);

        aVTOMOBILIBindingSource1.ResetBindings(true);
        ApplyDefaultUserFilter();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить текущий **DataRow** можно так:

```
DataRow car = (aVTOMOBILIBindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row;
```